# JQuery validating file inputs

Tags: jquery, validation

I am making my own custom validation.  At the moment I have

```
function doValidation(formData, jqForm, options) {

    var errors = [];

    var fullName = $.trim($("#fullName").val());
    var emailAdd = $.trim($("#emailAdd").val());
    var accountNum = $.trim($("#accountNum").val());

    var fileOne = $.trim($("#fileOne").val());
    var fileTwo = $.trim($("#fileTwo").val());

    if(fullName.length == 0) {
        errors.push("- Please input your Full name as per Passport");
    }

    if(fullName.length > 80) {
        errors.push("- Please input your Full name as per Passport");
    }

    if( !validateEmail(emailAdd)) {
        errors.push("- Your Email address is not in the correct format");
    }

    if(accountNum.length != 14) {
        errors.push("- Your Account number is not valid");
    }


    if (errors.length > 0) {
        $('#validation-results').css('display', 'block');
        $('#validation-results').html(errors.join('<br>'));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As you can see I have fileOne and fileTwo.  These are file input fields.  I am trying to achieve something but I am having difficulty.

How can I make sure that the file is of a certain type and size?  My files should be less than 2MB and one of these

> "image/bmp, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png, image/tiff,
>   application/pdf"

Additionally, both fields are not required, it can be one or the other (or both).  Is there any way to achieve this?  With JQuery validation, I used require_from_group.  I can't use JQuery validation anymore so trying to replicate something similar.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : You can't do file size validations **reliably** with client-side Javascript.

**Edit as per user comment -  ** JQuery Validation uses the Files API within the HTML5 browser to support client side file operations. However the support for the File API is not reliable across browsers. Refer to this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) and this [link](https://html5test.com/) for details.

By design the Javascript within the browser runs in a sandbox and cannot actually access arbritary files on the disk. So it cannot even come to calculate their sizes (which would need a call to the OS-specific API).

In order to check the file type - an elementary check could be to validate the extension from the file name in the file input. However, this is not reliable nothing stops the user from uploading a ZIP file instead of an image by changing the extension from .ZIP to .JPG.

Hence the correct place to perform this validation would be the server - which receives the byte contents of the uploaded file and then performs the necessary validations. Note that if you do these validations on the server you validation logic would be the same no matter from which user-agent and which OS platform the file is being uploaded.

Hope this helps

Comment: How does the JQuery Validation plugin deal with file size?

Comment: Ok .. I did not know that HTML 5 has a Files API which is used by Jquery validation that allows you to help you do that validation. However I am still skeptical about the reliablity of the support across browser versions

Answer (score 0):

You can get files from form from input `input.files`and this is a list. Object on list should be a instance of `File` where you can find all data for client side file validation:

[image: Example]

Please have a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File for more details.